# movie playback small not full size

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, sdk

I am developing a iphone app and I have a uiwebview which has a video on the page. When I press play the video plays in full screen. Is there a way I can make it so when I press play the video plays in a custom size and not full screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MPMoviePlayerController`

From Apple:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```